# Interface builder: does it establish an observer relationship on bound properties?

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, xcode7

In one of my xibs I have labels bound to properties of a represented object I set for the file's owner. The represented object is of type id and manually updated by a view controller. This is very similar you would do for cells/views in a tableview where it works nicely.

[image]

However, in this case the used view doesn't seem to recognize changes to the represented object, i.e. I can change the entire object or just that value without any visual effect and I wonder why. Doesn't the object inspector establish an observer relationship for the label to the bound property?

I tried to explicitly send willChangeValueForKey + didChangeValueForKey messages, but that didn't help (which brings me to the assumption there is no observer, even though that should be implicit). What's wrong here?

**Update**
Maybe this has to do with how the xib/nib is loaded, so here's that code:

```
NSNib *cellNib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed: nibName bundle: bundle];
NSArray *objects = nil;

[cellNib instantiateWithOwner: nil topLevelObjects: &objects];
```

Could it be that I'd need to set an owner? Is that the value known as "File's Owner" in IB? But if so, why did it work with the test property before?

Comment: Does one label not work or is it the whole xib? Does a model key path without self work? How do you change representedObject and purpose?

Comment: Also: How are you loading the NIB? Are you sure you've specified an owner loaded it in a way that it gets an owner implicitly? Are you sure that's the object on which you're changing the `representedObject`? (That is, are you sure you don't accidentally have two separate instances of your controller class and are operating on the wrong one?)

Comment: Seems it's the whole xib. I tried different labels, bound to representedObject or a test property. The value from the test property is shown, but only the initial one. Later changes are not visible in the xib. I also tried representedObject without self. prefix, to no avail. The representedObject is changed on demand (views are re-used in a list and when a new one comes into view it's updated by setting the representedObject from a controller).

Comment: @KenThomases I'm pretty sure it's otherwise all quite well and fine. I can manually update the entire UI without problems. All values are there and shown when I set them. It's only the binding that doesn't seem to listen to changes.

Comment: In response to your update: yes, you have to pass an owner. The object you pass as the owner to `-instantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:` is what fills the place being held by the File's Owner placeholder. If you think there's a chicken-and-egg problem, then you're probably doing something else wrong. The cell is not its own owner. A controller should be the owner and that controller must be something that is **not** instantiated in the NIB. It must be an object that already exists. You should use an `NSViewController` to load and own a view NIB or `NSWindowController` to load/own a window NIB.

Comment: I'm not sure I can fully agree with that. A view based NSTableView has no controller either and still can bind stuff successfully. My control is similar: a view that manages a set of subviews each loaded from the same xib.

Comment: A view-based table view uses the owner passed to `-makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:` as the File's Owner when it loads its cell-view NIBs. If the delegate doesn't implement `-tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` so that the call to `-makeView...` is implicit, it passes the delegate itself as the owner. I'm not sure what you think that has to do with anything, though. The nature of File's Owner is what it is, regardless of how the NIB is loaded or what view it might be incorporated into. If you don't pass an owner when you load the NIB, File's Owner will be `nil` and bindings through it won't work.

Comment: Yes, you certainly have a point here. All I wanna say is that it (mostly) worked without an owner in many cases before. But I'll see if I can restructure my xibs so that I can use a controller as owner. In the meantime you could prepare an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `nil` as the NIB owner when you call `-[NSNib instantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:]`. The owner you pass here is the object that fills the place being held by the File's Owner placeholder. Since you aren't specifying an owner object, no object fills that place. None of the connections established to or from File's Owner will actually be established when the NIB is loaded. That included bindings from views to or through File's Owner.

I recommend that you use `NSViewController` or a custom subclass to load and own a view NIB. Similarly, I recommend that you use `NSWindowController` or a custom subclass to load and own a window NIB.

As a special case, when a view-based table view automatically loads a NIB to get a cell view or row view, you can expect that the File's Owner will be the table view's delegate. This can be useful for connections *to* File's Owner. However, for connections *from* File's Owner, this is not useful because the same object will be the owner of many such NIBs and, for example, an outlet can't be connected to a subview in all of them simultaneously.

(Technically, your table view delegate can implement `-tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` and call `-makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:` with an owner other than `self`. But remember that `-makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:` can return a view from the table's reuse queue rather than loading a NIB. If it doesn't load a NIB, the owner parameter isn't used. So, you can't really change the owner of a view each time it's reused. And you have to make sure that the owner lives as long as the view.)